# How do you merge lines in a single dataset with some duplicate values?

Tags: merge, sas, duplicates

I am analyzing a medical record dataset where the patients were screened for STIs at 4 different times points. The data manager created a line per patient per STI for each time period. I want to merge the dataset so there is one line per patient at each time point with all of the diagnosed STI listed.

I created the new variables to capture each STI that would be listed under the Dx variable, but I can't figure out how to merge data within the same dataset so there is only one per patient at each timepoint.

```
data dx; 
set dx; 
if dx='ANOGENITAL WARTS (CONDYLOMATA ACUMINATA)' then MRWarts=1;
if dx='CHLAMYDIA' then MRCHLAMYDIA=1;
if dx='DYSPLASIA (ANAL, CERVICAL, OR VAGINAL)' then MRDYSPLASIA=1;
if dx='GONORRHEA' then MRGONORRHEA=1;
if dx='HEPATITIS B (HBV)' then MRHEPB=1;
if dx='HUMAN PAPILLOMAVIRUSES (HPV)-ANY MANIFESTATION' then MRHPV=1;
if dx='PEDICULOSIS PUBIS' then MRPUBIS=1;
if dx='SYPHILIS' then MRSYPHILIS=1;
if dx='TRICHOMONAS VAGINALIS' then MRTRICHOMONAS=1;
run;
```

[Image of data structure I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVvlG.png)

Comment: providing images is usually a bad idea.  If you want to get help, make it easy for people to help you.  Post instead your sample data in a form that makes it easy for someone to experiment with your data.  Look into proc transpose()

Comment: Okay, thank you for the feedback DCR. Will do going forward!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taking the sample dataset that you provided in the image, you can use simple transpose for desired outcome.

```
data have;
input Pt_ID interval_round DX $10.;
datalines;
4 1 HIV
4 1 Warts
3 1 HIV
5 2 Chlamydia
;
run;

proc sort data=have1; by Pt_Id; run;

proc transpose data=have1 out=want(drop=_NAME_);
by Pt_Id;
id Dx;
var interval_round;
run;

proc print data=want; run;
```

Now this code will create all variables except interval_round, Say for example - a patient was screened for HIV in round 1 and Warts for round 2. Technically it should have only one row .. so how would you represent the interval_round then?

Comment: Thank you for your input! I was able to format it the way I wanted with one line per patient per interval with the following code

Comment: proc sort data=dx; 
by Pt IntRound; 
run;

proc transpose data=dx out=want(drop=_NAME_);
by Pt IntRound;
var dx;
run;

Comment: great!! you can tweak the response as per requirement

Comment: great!! you can tweak the response as per requirement